# Incorrect fields showing up in Pivottable generated in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am building a VBA script to automatically make a Pivottable in Excel with data that I have in a table.
I use said table as data source for the Pivottable I generate, and I want to use the table headers as fields for the Pivottable.

However, instead of the table column headers, I get the entries from the first row of each column as fields.

Attached below is a snippet of the code I use to try and accomplish this, and a link to a screenshot of the actual fields i get in the Pivottable, the fields I want, and a small snippet of the actual table data.
Note: 2 columns in the table are hidden because of long strings and redundancy of data.

```
'Declare some variables to be used
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim field As PivotField

'Set source and target sheet
Set rngSource = Sheets("MergedData").Range("Table1")
Set wsTarget = Sheets("PivotData")

'Delete all pivottables in the target sheet
For Each xPT In Worksheets("PivotData").PivotTables
    Worksheets("PivotData").Range(xPT.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next

'Create a PivotTable with the data from the previously created table
Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rngSource, xlPivotTableVersion14)
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(wsTarget.Range("A1"), "PivotTable1", , xlPivotTableVersion14)

'Set all columns and rows for the pivottable
Set field = wsTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")
field.Orientation = xlColumnField

Set field = wsTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ErrorCode")
field.Orientation = xlRowField

Set field = wsTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Vehicle")
field.Orientation = xlRowField

Set field = wsTarget.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Vehicle")
field.Orientation = xlDataField
```

#### Image with Pivottable fields and table data

[image: Image with Pivottable fields and table data]

Long story short, how can I change the code so that the table headers are used as fields instead of the data in the first row of each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheets("MergedData").Range("Table1")
```

applies to table range without headers, use

```
Sheets("MergedData").ListObjects("Table1").Range
```

instead

Comment: Here's my gold standard reference for pivot table ranges: [Jon Peltier's Pivot Table reference](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/)

Comment: But the problem Youri has does not concern pivot table ranges but source data range